# Find the player of the year Algorithm JavaScript/Java

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pseudocode

**Can anyone please help me out on this one, I do not really understand sample input format. Can somebody guide me with the pseudocode of this algorithm ??**

There are multiple line graphs that denote the performance of star players in different sports teams.

The player of the year has the longest time as the number one player, i.e. the player whose graph values stay above the values of all players for the longest time.

**Find the player of the year.**

*Input Format*

The first line contains an integer, n, denoting the number of players.
The next line contains an integer, m, denoting the number of data points per player.
Each line i of the n subsequent lines(where 0 ≤ i < n)contains m space separated integers denoting the relative performance of player i during that data point duration.

*Output Format*

A single Integer

Sample Input

```
3 
4
1 3 4 5
7 2 3 4
1 3 2 1
```

Sample Output

```
0
```

Explanation

```
Player 0 has been on the top for 3 data point durations, which is the maximum.
```

Approach.

```
function Logic() {
//INPUT [uncomment & modify if required]
 let sampleInput = gets();
 let result = -404;


//OUTPUT [uncomment & modify if required]
console.log(result)

}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have n players and m data points, you get all the data points of a player before moving to the next player. That's it for the input format. If you store that in a matrix the same way as the sample input, then you need to find the row (player) which has the most column maximums. So basically you get the maximum for each column and all players having that value in that column get a point. The player with the most points wins. This is the algorithm.

Comment: The code that you provide under the title "Approach" does nothing. Did you just provide template code? How can that count as an "approach"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the sample input, a visual representation may be helpful:

[image]

The performance is on the vertical axis, the moments of measurement on the horizontal axis (4 data points), and each player is identified by colour.

The challenge is then to find the colour of the bars that reach highest during the longest consecutive period of time. In this case blue bars represent the maximum performance during 3 consecutive periods (labelled 2, 3 and 4).

#### Algorithm

In a first phase identify for each period which is the top performance value. So in the example that is: 7, 3, 4 and 5.

Then find the longest consecutive sequence in the performances of each player that matches that top performance. In this case the performance sequence 3, 4 and 5 is achieved by player 0, and is the longest such sequence.

#### Implementation

A JavaScript snippet:

```js
function getPlayerOfTheYear(series) {
    // The following two values are actually part of the input, 
    // but since this function takes a 2D array, they are implied:
    let playerCount = series.length;
    let periodCount = series[0].length;
    // 1. Collect all best performance values (= top of the "graph")
    let tops = []; 
    for (let i = 0; i < periodCount; i++) {
        // Get best performance for this particular period:
        let bestPerformance = -Infinity;
        for (let player = 0; player < playerCount; player++) {
            bestPerformance = Math.max(bestPerformance, series[player][i]);
        }
        tops.push(bestPerformance);
    }
    // 2. Per player, find longest sequence of achieving the top performance
    let longestDuration = 0;
    for (let player = 0; player < playerCount; player++) {
        let duration = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < periodCount; i++) {
            if (series[player][i] === tops[i]) {
                duration++;
                if (duration > longestDuration) {
                    playerOfTheYear = player;
                    longestDuration = duration;
                }
            } else duration = 0;
        }
    }
    return playerOfTheYear;
}

let player = getPlayerOfTheYear([
    [1, 3, 4, 5],
    [7, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 3, 2, 1]
]);

console.log("Player of the year: ", player);
```